# ADO.NET Ef4- How can i map a entity to stored procedure without mapping to table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We are using ado.net entity framework 4.0 for our database layer and I am a newbie to ado.net entity framework. I have created entity via adding a entity in entity framework. I want to map that entity with stored procedure only not table of the database. Stored procedure will return same column as entity. How it is possible and how i can do that without mapping to table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete walkthrough http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716679.aspx

Comment: I just want to bind entity with stored procedure not with database tables. The walk-though you suggested does not say this.

Comment: If you want just to retrieve entity via store proc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716672.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible because an ObjectSet is an IQueryable and mapping an ObjectSet to stored procedure would not give u an IQueryable because stored procedures by their very nature cannot be composed. The best you can do is take the content inside the stored procedure and put into a view and map the view to an ObjectSet which is possible.

Comment: It is possible with linq-to-sql then why its not possible with Entity framework? I have done that many time with Linq.

Comment: What I am saying that I don't want a entity to bind with tables. I want to use this entity as a result of my stored procedures select statement like select productid,productname from product and there will be a prouct class which will have those proeperties. But I don't want to bind product to product tables I just want to bind that with stored procedure.

Comment: ok rest assured, it is not supported. There has been internal debates on this issue but i am not sure if this would be supported in near future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a complex type, not an entity. Open up the model browser and import your stored procedure as a "function import" (your SP must not use #tempTables but you can use @tableVariables instead); in the function import wizard you'll see a "create complex type" button.

The SP becomes a method in the model context and you can use it to get IEnumerable[TheComplexType].

In EF4.1 code-first it's even simpler, you put a [ComplexType] attribute on top of any class and you can use that type as a return type for context.ExecuteStoreQuery[T]. If your properties are named exactly as the returned columns are (and the types line up), the mapping is "magic" - it just works.